# Where can I find a formula chord chart for minor keys?

Tags: theory

Where can I find a formula chord chart for minor keys?

All the ones I see in Google images are for major keys. How come?

Comment: I found this http://musictheory.pugetsound.edu/mt21c/DiatonicChordsInMinor.html It’s not a formula chart but it spells them all out in Am which is helpful.

Comment: Where can i find X questions are off-topic, but the core question seems to be about minor key harmony so I've closed this question as a dupe the goes over the basics of minor key harmony.

Comment: Lookong for chordcharts formulas: https://www.google.com/search?q=piano+chord+formula+chart+pdf&rlz=1C9BKJA_enCH812CH813&oq=formula+chord+chart&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0i22i30l4j69i60.15150j0j7&hl=de&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#imgrc=_ https://www.google.com/search?q=piano+chord+formula+chart+pdf&rlz=1C9BKJA_enCH812CH813&oq=formula+chord+chart&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0i22i30l4j69i60.15150j0j7&hl=de&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#imgrc=pkn_Te9TyWR-MM   major and minor

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli  Well those are all major. Hence the question.

Comment: No, there are always 2 columns, major and minor.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli  Yes, they are the minor chord formulas relative to the major key. The formula for a minor chord in a natural minor key would be 1-3-5.

Answer (score 2):

It's because there's more than one minor scale.

In the natural minor, the chords are the same as the major scale, but they fall on different scale tones:

i=minor
ii=diminished
III=Major
iv=minor
v=minor
VI=Major
VII=Major

Using the harmonic minor scale, any chord with the 7th scale degree changes:
III=augmented
V=Major
vii=diminished

And if you use the melodic minor* any chord with the 6th scale degree can change:
ii=minor
IV=Major
vi=diminished

*often defined as the "melodic minor ascending", but in practice composers may use a raised sixth when the melody is descending

Comment: For clarity it might be good to point out that the changes in harmony for the melodic minor also include the changes mentioned  for the harmonic minor...